# Is there a software that can perform recorded user actions at a later date?

Tags: macros, anti-virus, screen-recorder

Is there a software that is able to record and perform the actions (clicks, entering of text, etc) that can be replayed at a later date. For example, I often place downloaded software into the same directory and I want to scan the directory with one or more antivirus software with just a single click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called AutoIt that can script user actions. Other options would be to look for command line options for your av programs that would allow you to run the scan from a batch file.
 http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: I saw the title and opened the question to give this exact answer, +1 for the best automation software around.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options here. For windows, use can use VBscript for duplicating macro-style functionality. In OS X Applescript can help out with some of this. These are some built in tools. I'm sure that there are other one's out there, but I personally would opt for writing a shell script (OS X or Linux/Unix) or a batch file in windows to do what I need to do. Easy, customizable, and you can probably make it do what you want.